# Corner kitchen cabinet hinge - terminology help needed!

Tags: cabinets

I need to replace a hinge identical to this. It is from a corner kitchen cabinet that conceals a Lazy Susan. I've gleaned that these might be called salice hinges. The issue is this, and again my terminology fails me: on this one, as the pictures show, both sides of the hinge are recessed into the door. On the replacement hinges I've found online, all of them have one side the recesses, and the other side that doesn't. What would the correct terminology would be so that I can search successfully for a replacement hinge? Thanks in advance!
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hrKEH.jpg)

[image]

[image]

Comment: Looks like some type of *offset hinge*.

Comment: go to cabinet store

Comment: Around here,  you would go to a store that specialises on window and door hardware. Search for the store instead of the product.

Comment: How about something like this? https://www.amazon.com/corner-hinge-degree-nickel-plated/dp/B00OGBUYLE  Or just search "pie cut corner hinge" and see what you get.